# How do I stop PHP output buffering from eating error messages?

Tags: php, logging, error-reporting, output-buffering

Well, now that I've gotten a bit further into it, I realize that this is a stupid question, and wrong. Turns out that the author of the legacy code I maintain was hi-jacking the error log to a different file with a `php_init` statement. The hi-jacking occurred at the same time as the output buffering was turned on, making it *appear* as though output buffering was throwing away my error messages.

So, Mr. Moderator, feel free to delete this. Thanks to those who answered in good faith.

---

Given the following PHP script:

```
<?php 
error_log('test'); 

ob_start();

error_log('test2');

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I get the following error log output:

```
[04-Feb-2010 11:30:38] test
```

Why is output buffering eating my error messages? How can I make it stop?

Alternately, is there another way to smuggle messages out of an output buffer, or is it simply a black hole?

(Using PHP `5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Exceptions penetrate ob_start() shield

If you want to stop PHP script execution, rather throw an **Exception**, which will penetrate the ob_start(), ob_end_flush() shield

```
echo 'before output buffer';
ob_start();
throw new Exception('this will be seen');
ob_end_flush();
```

---

### Consider creating a Logger class

**Don't output directly** with your method, rather use a class or a `holder` which incorporates the log (or `error` method in your case), eg:

```
class Logger
{
    private $_messages = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_messages['errors'] = array();
        $this->_messages['debug'] = array();
    }

    public function error($msg)
    {
        $this->_messages['errors'][] = $msg;
    }

    public function debug($msg)
    {
        $this->_messages['debug'] = $msg;
    }

    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->_messages['errors'];
    }

}

$logger = new Logger();

$logger->error('error1');

ob_start();

$logger->error('error2');

ob_end_flush();

print_r($logger->getErrors());
```

this way you can rely on the holder object, it will not discard messages and get all errors, that you wanted to display

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this in practice, but this should work:

You would have to build a wrapper around error_log() that

1. stores the output you are buffering using ob_get_contents()
2. erases the output buffer using ob_clean()
3. writes out the error message and ob_flush()es it
4. writes back the stored output using echo()

Comment: This isn't *my* error_log function, this is PHP's: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: Ah, all right. Still, the general point still stands. I edited my answer a bit.